# Yeoman Angular.js grunt serve-d app has very long latency from livereload.js?snipver=1

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I followed [Yeoman's guide](http://yeoman.io/) to set up an Angular.js app.  **I didn't change anything** except for the hostname from "localhost" to "0.0.0.0".

When I did `grunt serve`, there were no errors. Eventually I do get to see the "'Allo, 'Allo" front page, but only after over **30 seconds of latency from livereload.js?snipver=1**, which failed to GET. As you can see on the right, the server doesn't output anything unusual.

[image: livereload.js failed and causes a long latency]

My entire project [is on github](https://github.com/randwa1k/testangular).

I grep-ped for livereload and found a few suspects:

- `/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect-livereload/index.js` has these two functions below containing the livereload url. The first one links to "http://my.ip.addr.ess:9000/livereload.js", which has a "Cannot GET".

  ```
  function getSnippet() {
      /*jshint quotmark:false */
      var snippet = [ 
          "<!-- livereload script -->",
          "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.write('<script src=\"http://'",
          " + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0]",
          " + ':" + port + "/livereload.js?snipver=1\" type=\"text/javascript\"><\\/  script>')",
          "</script>",
          ""  
      ].join('\n');
      return snippet;
    };    

    function snippetExists(body) {
      if (!body) return true;
      return (~body.lastIndexOf("/livereload.js?snipver=1"));
    }
  ```
- My [Gruntfile.js](https://gist.github.com/randwa1k/9106462) which set livereload to be true, which I would like to keep.

Does anyone have a clue?

---

Update:

I tried on a brand new machine again, [from scratch](https://gist.github.com/randwa1k/9167694). I still get the same problem!  This time the Status of livereload says "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

[image]

More information: I'm running on AWS EC2 with only ports 8000 and 9000 open.

---

Comment: Post it as an issue on yeoman's github. Or look it up there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After thinking about it, I determined that it couldn't have been Yeoman or any of my Ubuntu server's fault, because nothing changed after I wiped the machine clean and started over. It wasn't a blocked IP on the browser either, because both Chrome and Firefox had the same problem. It wasn't a blocked IP on my client machine because the problem persisted on another machine.

The light bulb went off when I actually looked into the exact URL livereload was requesting. It was requesting on port 35729, a port I haven't opened up on my AWS EC2 account!

[image]

After I opened up that port, it worked flawlessly!